# CSS flex align buttons

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to learn to align buttons correctly using flex.

On desktop looks like I want it:

[image]

So does in portrait on mobile:

[image]

However when on landscape, it looks like this:

[image]

I'd prefer it would look more align.

Here's my code for this part:

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btnWrap col" style="">
      <button type="button" id="TopNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top active" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Najpogostejša imena</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btnWrap col" style="">
      <button type="button" id="TopBabyNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Imena novorojenčkov</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btnWrap col" style="">
      <button type="button" id="TopDisappearingNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Izginjajoča imena</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btnWrap col" style="">
      <button type="button" id="TopModernNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Sodobna imena</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btnWrap col" style="">
      <button type="button" id="TopLastnames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Najpogostejši priimki</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough code here to reproduce the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): "Use as little code as possible ... Provide all parts someone else needs ... make sure it reproduces the problem".

Comment: We don't know, what your expected result is. Could you be more specific?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap, add tag of it

Answer (score 0):

This is how your html should be:

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
   <button>Name</button>
   <button>Name</button>
   <button>Name</button>
   <button>Name</button>
   <button>Name</button>
</div>
```

This is css for desktop:

```
.button-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
```

This is css for mobile:

```
.button-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add extra CSS property here, instead of that use bootstrap classes

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-md-6 col-lg" style="">
            <button type="button" id="TopNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top active" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Najpogostejša imena</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-md-6 col-lg" style="">
            <button type="button" id="TopBabyNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Imena novorojenčkov</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-md-4 col-lg" style="">
            <button type="button" id="TopDisappearingNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Izginjajoča imena</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-md-4 col-lg" style="">
            <button type="button" id="TopModernNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Sodobna imena</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-md-4 col-lg" style="">
            <button type="button" id="TopLastnames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Najpogostejši priimki</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below snippet. Add bootstrap classes to achieve desired result

```css
.btnWrap{
margin-top:10px
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-lg" >
            <button type="button" id="TopNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top active" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Najpogostejša imena</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-lg" >
            <button type="button" id="TopBabyNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Imena novorojenčkov</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-lg" >
            <button type="button" id="TopDisappearingNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Izginjajoča imena</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-lg" >
            <button type="button" id="TopModernNames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Sodobna imena</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btnWrap col-12 col-lg" >
            <button type="button" id="TopLastnames" class="btn btn-secondary btn-top" onclick="topButtonClick(this)">Najpogostejši priimki</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer it not correct, because OP needs 2 / 3 columns in row and your answer not satisfied this need